# Printing a List Contained in a Struct

Tags: c++11, graph

```
// struct representing every edge in the graph
template<class Type>
struct Vertex
{
  Type info;
  list<vertexConnection<Type> >adjacents;
};
```

This is how I try to print it but I am getting errors

```
for(int i=0; i <count; i++)
{
  typename list<vertexConnectivity<Type> >::iterator j;

  list<vertexConnection<Type> > s = node[i].adjacents;

  for(j = s.begin(); j != s.end(); ++j)
  {
    cout << *j;
  }
}
```

How do I print the content in the list adjacents that is of type vertexConnection which on the other hand is of type Type.

The errors I am getting are:

1. at the line with **cout << *j;**

graph.h:313:2: error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << j.std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::operator* with _Tp = GraphNameSpace::vertexConnectivity, std::_List_iterator<_Tp>::reference = GraphNameSpace::vertexConnectivity&’

2. line is **ostream& operator <<(ostream&, Country&);**

country.h:24:10: note: std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream&, Country&)
country.h:24:10: note:   no known conversion for argument 2 from ‘GraphNameSpace::vertexConnectivity’ to ‘Country&’

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`*j` is a `vertexConnection<Type>` but you never provided any instructions to your compiler on *how* to represent that as text. You want to stream it to `std::cout`: okay, but *how*? According to what rules and logic?

You'll need to write a stringise function and call it, or overload `operator<<` for that type:

```
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const vertexConnection<T>&);
```

At the moment your compiler is pointing out that you did at least provide one for `Country` objects, but that it can't be used in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

1. Use range-based for loop (C++11 feature) to simplify element visit. 
   Please see http://herbsutter.com/elements-of-modern-c-style/
2. Provide overloaded operator<< for each of your user defined types.

For example,

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, const Country& c);
```